# Remove Parse-specific fields from database results

Tags: mongodb, parse-platform, parse-server, data-cleaning, database

Every time I query something from database I get objects like this:

```
{
  "title": "faq",
  "description": "",
  "type": "application/pdf",
  "size": 122974,
  "filename": "faq.pdf",
  "order": 0,
  "createdAt": "2017-08-17T08:10:33.101Z",
  "updatedAt": "2017-08-17T08:10:33.101Z",
  "ACL": {
    "role:cxcccccc_public": {
      "read": true
    },
    "role:cxaaaaaaa_admin": {
      "read": true,
      "write": true
    }
  },
  "objectId": "l6L5J1mRpH",
  "__type": "Object",
  "className": "Document"
}
```

A lot of these fields are Parse-specific: `createdAt`, `updatedAt`, `ACL`, `className`...

I didn't insert them when I added the row in the database but still they are returned when I do a query.

I want to expose this data through a clean REST API so I want to get rid of them.

Is there a way to get only the data I specified at insert time?

For now I am using lowdash, filtering with

```
data = _.omit(data, ['ACL', '__type', 'className', ...])
```

Comment: If I understood your post correctly, you imported your (old) Parse.com/parse-server data into a new database and want to create a new (without using parse-server) REST API from it without all the parse.com system attributes ? Do you want to delete the attributes and it's corresponding data physically from the database or just not show them in your endpoints ?

Comment: @nathan I am using the open source version of the Parse backend. I want to expose a REST API from it that doesn't show the Parse-specific attributes in the response. I don't want to delete them since they could be useful in some cases, but they are overkill for most REST responses.

Comment: But are you going to expose your API by interfacing with Parse's SDK or directly with mongo ?

Comment: With Parse SDK, using `Parse.Cloud.define('endpointName', fn)`. I am new to this so I may be doing something terribly wrong.